# What is the most reliable method to UPDATE table on browser close?

Tags: php, browser, timeout, sql-update, logout

My website has a login script that checks user data from a mysql table. The table has several columns (name, username, pass, etc.), the most important (for the sake of this question) being the 'username' and 'online' columns. The 'online' column is a BOOL value (1 when online is true, 0 when false). When a user successfully logs in, $_SESSION variables are set to their data from the table, and I use the following to change the 'online' value from '0' to '1' in the table.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET Online='1' Where UserName='$username' AND Online='0'");
```

The script checks the value of 'online' so that if it is 1, they cannot log in, echoing a message stating that the user is already logged in.

Next, each page of the site has a 'log out' link that runs a script that unsets all $_SESSION variables and updates the online value from 1 back to 0.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET Online='0' Where UserName='$username' AND Online='1'");
```

This is where the problem comes in. If a user closes the browser window, the session ends automatically due to how php functions, which is fine because that's what I want to happen. However, I'd also like to update the table if the browser is closed. Otherwise, when a user closes their browser, they will not be able to log back in due to the fact that their online value is still 1. I know the using onunload or onbeforeunload won't work because that would run every time they refresh or change pages. I know I probably need to use some sort of session timeout, but every answer I've seen doesn't full explain how to go about doing that. I generally just see people post code without explaining how exactly it works or how it's supposed to be used. If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you treat 'online' and 'logged in' as meaning the same thing. If so, I wouldn't duplicate the logged in state in the database, but just check to see if the $SESSION cookie is set or not to determine their logged in state.

Comment: yes, this is not the standard approach to how most websites use logins. they mostly just use sessions. my advice would be forget about using tables to store "logged in" or not. as you have discovered, if someone closes their browser, there is not much you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, on my home page, I like to display which users are currently online. Would I not need to have this data stored in the database, or is there another way to do this? I'm fairly new to php/mysql, so I'm trying to get all the help I can. Reading tutorials and manuals will only get me so far; I like hearing solutions from other people's experiences. All the help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to auto-refresh any script and if last activity > 5 minutes -> SQL query.

Comment: This is probably the most robust solution. You can even skip the SQL query and when the user tries to login, just check if last activity was more than five minutes ago and allow them in.